# Excel get remote data from PHP script. Issue with authentication

Tags: php, excel, remote-access

I have an excel Worksheet connecting to a remote php page. The remote page is providing as output a table in HTML format that's rendered by Excel.

[image]

I'm not able to understand how the windows authenticated user account is transferred to php remote script. Can anybody help me?

What should I receive on php remote script?